# Flex: Is there anyway to disable the textfield in the NumericStepper and force the user to change the value only by using the up/down buttons?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, numericstepper

Probably not much more to elaborate on here - I'm using a NumericStepper control and I want the user to use the buttons only to change the value in the NS, not by typing into the control - I couldn't find a property to disable the text - does it exist?

If it doesn't, how would I subclass this thing to disable the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you're using mx_internal, there's a decent chance that your app will break between flex versions.

Comment: In many scenarios, there is no option but to use mx_internal. We have run across many such instances, so far never had an issue with  mx_internal usage causing version upgrade issues. They barely if ever touch the Halo code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I think I got it - there is no property you can set but you can subclass the control and set:

```
mx_internal::inputField.enabled = false;
```

Although that sets up next question about what the hell mx_internal is...

Answer (score 0):

mx_internal is a namespace. There's a good explanation of how it all works here:

http://nondocs.blogspot.com/2007/04/mxcoremxinternal.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spark NumericStepper, best practice is to create a custom skin and hide the TextInput part (its a required skin part so it has to be in the skin somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

text Input has property 'editable' which can be set to false. It worked for me.